# Installing Pygame and Pymunk on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: compilation, osx-snow-leopard, pygame, failed-installation, pymunk

I have not been able to install Pymunk and Pygame for the same version of python. I have tried binaries, source installs, fink, and Macports, for system python, python 2.6, and python 2.7, with 32 and 64 bit versions.

In some cases the pymunk unit tests cause a segmentation fault, in some cases I get symptoms similar to [Issue 42](http://code.google.com/p/pymunk/issues/detail?id=42), and in some I cannot import pymunk because libchipmunk.dylib is an incompatible architecture.

When I can install pymunk, I cannot install or compile pygame with extended image (`pygame.image.get_extended() == 0`) or font support, which largely defeats the purpose of using pygame and pymunk together. On some versions of python, such as 2.7 64 bit, I get

```
building 'pygame.imageext' extension
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Ddarwin -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/imageext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/src/imageext.o
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccuP0D3r.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

When importing pygame, I sometimes get:

```
from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

I haven't had any issues on Ubuntu or Windows, so I think the problem is OS X-specific.

I am somewhat new to makefiles and compile flags, and I have been trying to set up these two modules for three days, so if someone could provide me with a detailed installation procedure that actually works for them, including the relevant .bash_profile and environment variables, I would be extremely grateful.

**Edit:** I reinstalled python, pygame, and chipmunk+pymunk, and this is the error I am getting with Python 2.7 (32 bit):

```
$ python2.7-32 flipper.py 
Loading chipmunk for Darwin (32bit) [/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib]
2011-10-03 19:03:08.862 Python[3683:60f] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
Initializing cpSpace - Chipmunk v6.0.1 (Debug Enabled)
Compile with -DNDEBUG defined to disable debug mode and runtime assertion checks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flipper.py", line 35, in <module>
    space.add_static(static_lines)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/__init__.py", line 288, in add_static
    self.add_static(oo)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/__init__.py", line 285, in add_static
    self._add_static_shape(o)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/__init__.py", line 327, in _add_static_shape
    assert static_shape._hashid_private not in self._static_shapes, "shape already added to space"
AssertionError: shape already added to space
```

**Edit 2:** Despite changing the setup.py file to only link for 32-bit, I am getting some odd behavior:

```
$ sudo python setup.py build_chipmunk
running build_chipmunk
compiling chipmunk...
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/chipmunk.c -o chipmunk_src/chipmunk.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpArbiter.c -o chipmunk_src/cpArbiter.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpArray.c -o chipmunk_src/cpArray.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpBB.c -o chipmunk_src/cpBB.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpBBTree.c -o chipmunk_src/cpBBTree.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpBody.c -o chipmunk_src/cpBody.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpCollision.c -o chipmunk_src/cpCollision.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpHashSet.c -o chipmunk_src/cpHashSet.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpPolyShape.c -o chipmunk_src/cpPolyShape.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpShape.c -o chipmunk_src/cpShape.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSpace.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSpace.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSpaceComponent.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceComponent.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSpaceHash.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceHash.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSpaceQuery.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceQuery.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSpaceStep.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceStep.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSpatialIndex.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSpatialIndex.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSweep1D.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSweep1D.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpVect.c -o chipmunk_src/cpVect.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpConstraint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpConstraint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpDampedRotarySpring.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpDampedRotarySpring.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpDampedSpring.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpDampedSpring.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpGearJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpGearJoint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpGrooveJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpGrooveJoint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpPinJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpPinJoint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpPivotJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpPivotJoint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpRatchetJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpRatchetJoint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpRotaryLimitJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpRotaryLimitJoint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpSimpleMotor.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpSimpleMotor.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpSlideJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpSlideJoint.o
cc -dynamiclib -arch i386 chipmunk_src/chipmunk.o chipmunk_src/cpArbiter.o chipmunk_src/cpArray.o chipmunk_src/cpBB.o chipmunk_src/cpBBTree.o chipmunk_src/cpBody.o chipmunk_src/cpCollision.o chipmunk_src/cpHashSet.o chipmunk_src/cpPolyShape.o chipmunk_src/cpShape.o chipmunk_src/cpSpace.o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceComponent.o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceHash.o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceQuery.o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceStep.o chipmunk_src/cpSpatialIndex.o chipmunk_src/cpSweep1D.o chipmunk_src/cpVect.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpConstraint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpDampedRotarySpring.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpDampedSpring.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpGearJoint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpGrooveJoint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpPinJoint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpPivotJoint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpRatchetJoint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpRotaryLimitJoint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpSimpleMotor.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpSlideJoint.o -o pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib

$ python2.7-32
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymunk
Loading chipmunk for Darwin (32bit) [/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib]
>>> s = pymunk.Space()
Initializing cpSpace - Chipmunk v6.0.1 (Debug Enabled)
Compile with -DNDEBUG defined to disable debug mode and runtime assertion checks
>>> c1 = pymunk.Circle(s.static_body, 1)
>>> s.add(c1)
>>> c2 = pymunk.Circle(s.static_body, 2)
>>> s.add(c2) #No error!

$ sudo python setup.py install

$ python2.7-32 unittests.py 
Loading chipmunk for Darwin (32bit) [/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib]
testing pymunk version 2.0.0
Initializing cpSpace - Chipmunk v6.0.1 (Debug Enabled)
Compile with -DNDEBUG defined to disable debug mode and runtime assertion checks
FFFFSegmentation fault

$ python2.7-32 flipper.py 
Loading chipmunk for Darwin (32bit) [/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib]
2011-10-04 13:49:45.653 Python[6430:60f] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
Initializing cpSpace - Chipmunk v6.0.1 (Debug Enabled)
Compile with -DNDEBUG defined to disable debug mode and runtime assertion checks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flipper.py", line 35, in <module>
    space.add_static(static_lines)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/__init__.py", line 288, in add_static
    self.add_static(oo)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/__init__.py", line 285, in add_static
    self._add_static_shape(o)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/__init__.py", line 327, in _add_static_shape
    assert static_shape._hashid_private not in self._static_shapes, "shape already added to space"
AssertionError: shape already added to space
```

**Edit 3:** Chipmunk now built and linked for x86, but I am getting the same errors:

```
$sudo python2.7-32 setup.py build_chipmunk
running build_chipmunk
compiling chipmunk...
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/chipmunk.c -o chipmunk_src/chipmunk.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpArbiter.c -o chipmunk_src/cpArbiter.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpArray.c -o chipmunk_src/cpArray.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpBB.c -o chipmunk_src/cpBB.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpBBTree.c -o chipmunk_src/cpBBTree.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpBody.c -o chipmunk_src/cpBody.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpCollision.c -o chipmunk_src/cpCollision.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpHashSet.c -o chipmunk_src/cpHashSet.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpPolyShape.c -o chipmunk_src/cpPolyShape.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpShape.c -o chipmunk_src/cpShape.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSpace.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSpace.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSpaceComponent.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceComponent.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSpaceHash.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceHash.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSpaceQuery.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceQuery.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSpaceStep.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceStep.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSpatialIndex.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSpatialIndex.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpSweep1D.c -o chipmunk_src/cpSweep1D.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/cpVect.c -o chipmunk_src/cpVect.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpConstraint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpConstraint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpDampedRotarySpring.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpDampedRotarySpring.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpDampedSpring.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpDampedSpring.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpGearJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpGearJoint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpGrooveJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpGrooveJoint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpPinJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpPinJoint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpPivotJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpPivotJoint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpRatchetJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpRatchetJoint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpRotaryLimitJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpRotaryLimitJoint.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpSimpleMotor.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpSimpleMotor.o
cc -O3 -std=gnu99 -ffast-math -fPIC -DCHIPMUNK_FFI -arch i386 -Ichipmunk_src/include/chipmunk -c chipmunk_src/constraints/cpSlideJoint.c -o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpSlideJoint.o
cc -dynamiclib -arch i386 chipmunk_src/chipmunk.o chipmunk_src/cpArbiter.o chipmunk_src/cpArray.o chipmunk_src/cpBB.o chipmunk_src/cpBBTree.o chipmunk_src/cpBody.o chipmunk_src/cpCollision.o chipmunk_src/cpHashSet.o chipmunk_src/cpPolyShape.o chipmunk_src/cpShape.o chipmunk_src/cpSpace.o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceComponent.o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceHash.o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceQuery.o chipmunk_src/cpSpaceStep.o chipmunk_src/cpSpatialIndex.o chipmunk_src/cpSweep1D.o chipmunk_src/cpVect.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpConstraint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpDampedRotarySpring.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpDampedSpring.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpGearJoint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpGrooveJoint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpPinJoint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpPivotJoint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpRatchetJoint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpRotaryLimitJoint.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpSimpleMotor.o chipmunk_src/constraints/cpSlideJoint.o -o pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib

$ sudo python2.7-32 setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
copying pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib -> build/lib/pymunk
running install_lib
copying build/lib/pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk
running install_egg_info
Removing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk-2.0.0-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk-2.0.0-py2.7.egg-info

$ python2.7-32 flipper.py 
Loading chipmunk for Darwin (32bit) [/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib]
2011-10-05 01:15:15.972 Python[3183:60f] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
Initializing cpSpace - Chipmunk v6.0.1 (Debug Enabled)
Compile with -DNDEBUG defined to disable debug mode and runtime assertion checks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flipper.py", line 35, in <module>
    space.add_static(static_lines)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/__init__.py", line 288, in add_static
    self.add_static(oo)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/__init__.py", line 285, in add_static
    self._add_static_shape(o)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/__init__.py", line 327, in _add_static_shape
    assert static_shape._hashid_private not in self._static_shapes, "shape already added to space"

$ python2.7-32 unittests.py 
Loading chipmunk for Darwin (32bit) [/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib]
testing pymunk version 2.0.0
Initializing cpSpace - Chipmunk v6.0.1 (Debug Enabled)
Compile with -DNDEBUG defined to disable debug mode and runtime assertion checks
FFFFSegmentation fault
```

**Edit 4:** Verification of versions and executable types:

```
$ file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib: Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
$ file "$( "$(which python2.7-32)" -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)" )"
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python (for architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
$ python2.7-32 -c "import sys;print('%x'%sys.maxint)"
7fffffff
```

Thanks in advance,

Julian Ceipek

Comment: Ah, maybe its wrong python version that does the building? should run build_chipmunk with your 32bit python:

sudo python2.7-32 setup.py build_chipmunk

I also spotted an error in my answer. The setup.py file needs two edits to compile in 32bit only.

Comment: Can you check what version you have of everything:
First, run the file tool on the dylib file:
`> file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib`

Then you can also verify what python is using:
`file "$( "$(which python2.7-32)" -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)" )"`
And finally verify that the python version is indeed 32bit
`>python2.7-32 -c "import sys;print('%x'%sys.maxint)"

Answer (score 1):

(I am the developer of pymunk)
I would suggest you start by getting pygame working. When you have pygame working on a specific python version, then move over and try to get pymunk working on that same version.

When you try with pymunk, the best way to get it working is

1. Get version directly from svn (tags/pymunk-2.0.0 contains the release version). Unfortunately the zip source distribution of 2.0.0 does not contain the chipmunk sources you need for compiling.
2. When you have pymunk including the sources, try compiling chipmunk with build_chipmunk (make sure you do this step with the same python version as you want to run it with)

   > python setup.py build_chipmunk
3. Hopefully you should now be able to run pymunk.

If this doesnt work its a bit more tricky.

If you're up for some experimenting you can try to modify the setup script to only build chipmunk in 32bit mode (by default it embeds both 32 and 64 bit versions into the dylib file on OSX). That way you will be sure it loads the 32 bit version.

In the setup.py file, http://code.google.com/p/pymunk/source/browse/tags/pymunk-2.0.0/setup.py
edit line 53 from:

```
compiler_preargs += ['-arch', 'i386', '-arch', 'x86_64']
```

into

```
compiler_preargs += ['-arch', 'i386']
```

and you will also need to edit line 66 from:

```
compiler.set_executable('linker_so', ['cc', '-dynamiclib', '-arch', 'i386', '-arch', 'x86_64'])
```

into

```
compiler.set_executable('linker_so', ['cc', '-dynamiclib', '-arch', 'i386'])
```

Then run

```
>python2.7-32 setup.py build_chipmunk
```

To test if it works you dont need to install the whole thing, you can try directly from the same folder:

```
>python
>>> import pymunk
>>> s = pymunk.Space()
>>> c1 = pymunk.Circle(s.static_body, 1)
>>> s.add(c1)
>>> c2 - pymunk.Cricle(s.static_body, 2)
>>> s.add(c2) #this line will fail if it still doesnt work
```

If you still have problem, then the output of this would be helpful (basically Im almost out of ideas here..)

First, run the file tool on the dylib file:

```
> file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymunk/libchipmunk.dylib
```

Then you can also verify what python is using:

```
> file "$( "$(which python2.7-32)" -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)" )"
```

And finally verify that the python version is indeed 32bit

```
> python2.7-32 -c "import sys;print('%x'%sys.maxint)"
```

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest in this.

$ python2.7-32 flipper.py 
[...]
AssertionError: shape already added to space

Comment: I expanded the answer a little bit, your error suggests that it tries to use the 64bit version of chipmunk even when using the 32bit python.

Comment: I followed your recommendation, but I am still getting the same error and all the unit tests fail.

Comment: I can't believe that I missed using the correct version of python earlier. Nonetheless, I am still seeing the same error after changing the setup file again.

Comment: Expanded my answer a little bit more.. Thanks for not giving up on pymunk :)

Comment: No problem; thanks for not giving up on me! Anyway, I posted the output of the tests, though I can't really say that I understand the output of the maxint test. Is it just failing for non-32 bit ints?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering, but I just went on a vacation which means I will have a little less time for pymunk the next two weeks. I dont have any ready good things to try right now but I will try to think of something. Im sure Ive seen the problem before so it must be possible to solve, just that its a little bit hard when I dont have OSX myself to try things on.

Comment: No problem. Just let me know when you have something else I can try.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I took a new look at the problem, but I cant really figure out something good to try :(

Comment: Having the same problem too on OSX Lion.